# Why is the confidence interval not consistent with the standard errors in this regression?

Tags: linear-regression, stata, standard-error

I am running a linear regression with fixed effect and standard errors clustered by a certain group.

```
 areg ref1 ref1_l1 rf1 ew1 vol_ew1 sk_ew1, a(us_id) vce(cluster us_id)
```

The one line code is as above and the output is as follows:
[image]

Now, the t-stats and the P values look inconsistent. How can we have t-stat >5 and pval >11%?. Similarly the 95% confidence intervals appear to be way wider than Coeff. +- 2 Std. Err.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inconsistent here. You have a small sample size and a less than parsimonious model and have all but run out of degrees of freedom. Notice how `areg` won't post an F statistic or a P-value for the model, a strong danger sign. Your t statistics are consistent with checks by hand:

```
. display 2 * ttail(1, 5.54)
.11368912

. display 2 * ttail(1, 113.1)
.00562868
```

In short, there is no bug here and no programming issue. It's just a matter of your model over-fitting your data and the side-effects of that.

Similarly, +/- 2 SE for a 95% confidence interval is way off as a rule of thumb here. Again, a hand calculation is instructive:

```
. display invt(1, 0.975)
12.706205

. display invt(60, 0.975)
2.0002978

. display invt(61, 0.975)
1.9996236

. display invnormal(0.975)
1.959964
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So does it make sense to produce clustered standard error at all when there are just two groups? The groups are countries. Country one as ~50 observations and country 2 has ~30 observations.

Comment: The issue is how many parameters you are estimating. not the use clustered SEs.